# How to debug hangfire jobs locally while not triggering scheduled jobs

Tags: c#, .net-core, hangfire

Is there a way to run Hangfire Jobs locally while debugging in Visual Studio while not triggereing any scheduled jobs defined in the database.

For example, I have HangfireJobA and I want to run it one time while in Visual Studio and step through it, however, when debugging, if HangfireJobA is configured in the DB to run every 3 minutes, I don't necessary want that schedule to be triggered.

How can I logically separate the two requirements. I don't want the scheduled jobs to run while I am debugging.

Currently, I have created a #IF(DEBUG) ...#endif and dynamically load all classes that implement an IServiceWorker interface and then select one to instantiate and run it's worker function. This seems hacky and there may be a better way. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution being test driven at the moment is:

1. Require all Developers install SQL Server LocalDB
2. In appsettings.local.json add the local version of the hangfire db.

   "HangfireDB": "Data Source = localhost; Initial Catalog = Hangfire_XXXX; Integrated Security = SSPI;"
3. In registration, there is a differentiation between debugging locally or running in a target environment.

NOTE : Adding Cron.Never() as the Schedule will place the job in a visible but *disabled* state. This means the only way to trigger a job is to implicitly click the "Trigger Now", thus invoking the debugger on it.

```
public static class RegisterServiceWorkers
{
    public static void Register(string environment)
    {
        if (environment.Equals("LOCAL"))
        {
                
            RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate<LeaseReportDataBuildupWorker>("LeaseReportDataBuildupWorker_LIFO", x => x.PerformServiceWork("LIFO"), () => Cron.Never());
            RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate<LeaseReportDataBuildupWorker>("LeaseReportDataBuildupWorker_FIFO", x => x.PerformServiceWork("FIFO"), () => Cron.Never());
            RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate<LeaseReportDataBuildupWorker>("LeaseReportDataBuildupWorker_RANDOM", x => x.PerformServiceWork("RANDOM"), () => Cron.Never());
        }
        else
        {
            RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate<LeaseReportDataBuildupWorker>("LeaseReportDataBuildupWorker_FIFO", x => x.PerformServiceWork("LIFO"), () => "*/3 * * * *");
            RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate<LeaseReportDataBuildupWorker>("LeaseReportDataBuildupWorker_LIFO", x => x.PerformServiceWork("FIFO"), () => "*/3 * * * *");
            RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate<LeaseReportDataBuildupWorker>("LeaseReportDataBuildupWorker_RANDOM", x => x.PerformServiceWork("RANDOM"), () => "*/3 * * * *");
        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a pretty simplified example, but you'll definitely get the idea. Assuming the following code:

```cs
public void AddRecurringJob() => RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate("helloworldjob", HelloWorld, Cron.Daily);

public void HelloWorld() => Console.Write("Hello World!");
```

What about changing `HelloWorld()` so something like this:

```cs
public void HelloWorld()
{
    if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached) return;

    Console.Write("Hello World!");
}
```

Since you're in the debugger, you can step over the `if` statement manually. Hangfire will pick up your job anyways, but since the debugger is attached, it will do nothing and return immediately.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback and I will upvote, however, I solved this in a different way. If you see any drawbacks the please leave feedback.